# inputField onchange does not fire

Tags: visualforce, actionsupport

I'm trying to get an inputField that is an account lookup to fire on the change event using actionSupport

```
<actionRegion>
    <apex:inputField id="accountId" value="{!tempAsset.AccountId}" 
        rendered="{! !invalidProfile}" required="true">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onblur" action="{!ChangeAccount}" 
            rerender="RERENDERS" />
    </apex:inputField>
</actionRegion>
```

> I've read that this is a known issue here:
>   https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HD0MAAW

Is there a workaround? I read that wrapping an actionRegion would resolve this, but it still does not fire.

Comment: `{!NOT(invalidProfile)}` is more readable than `{! !invalidProfile}` - 1 comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested code of passing value to Controller with `actionSupport` and without using `actionRegion`.

Rather than `onblur` event, you can use `onchange`.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page name="actionSupportPage" StandardController="Opportunity"  extensions="ActionSupportController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputLabel > AccountId: &nbsp;</apex:outputLabel>        
        <apex:inputField id="OpportunityId" value="{!opptyObj.AccountId}" required="true"> 
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="values" action="{!passValueToController}" >
             </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:inputField>

     <apex:outputText value="{!fieldValue}" label="You have selected:" id="values" /> 
</apex:form >
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ActionSupportController
{
    public Opportunity opptyObj{get;set;}
    public String fieldValue {get; set;}

    ApexPages.standardController stdController = null;
    public ActionSupportController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)     
    {
        this.stdController = controller;
        opptyObj = new Opportunity();
    }

    public void passValueToController()   
    {        
          fieldValue = opptyObj.AccountId;

    }

}
```